# unsafePerformIO when accessing dependent C resources

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm writing bindings (for the first time). On C level there are function to allocate some sort of resource, let's call it `ParentRes`. It returns `IO (Ptr ParentRes)`. Everytime `ParentRes` is created, a child resource allocated, let's call it `ChildRes`. This stuff is all static, child pointer cannot change and it's freed when parent resource is freed.

Now the catch: there is a function that takes pointer to parent and returns pointer to child:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "…"
  c_get_child_res :: Ptr ParentRes -> IO (Ptr ChildRes)
```

I want to write wrapper of type `Ptr ParentRes -> Ptr ChildRes` using `unsafePerformIO`. Is there a reason I should not do it?

Comment: Well, do you need it for anything?

Comment: @gspr, Well, this could reduce boilerplate a bit. Anyway, I've already coded more complex helpers that go through the "chain" and extract values inside IO then pull them from IO. Answer to this question would be still interesting, though.

Comment: Not answering the (interesting) question, but: if you decide to do this, you don't have to use `unsafePerformIO` explicitly, you can just remove `IO` from the type of the foreign import.

Comment: @ReidBarton, Hmm, in tutorial I read it's said that one should always use IO when passing or receiving pointers...

Comment: As I commented on an answer that seems to have been deleted, since you say that the child pointer is the same for the lifetime of the parent pointer, then `getChildRes x` will always have the same value, so `unsafePerformIO` should be safe. However, you don't want to give this function the type `Ptr A -> Ptr B`, because someone could do `getChildRes (castPtr x)` - you should have a newtype wrapper for `Ptr ParentRes` and `Ptr ChildRes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'm answering from my real experience that I have had just now because
of “pure” functions that are not quite pure.

I can formulate it in these words: everything that can be affected by order
of execution should always stay in `IO`. `IO` monad is Haskell is standard
and reliable way to ensure order of execution. If order matters, your
functions should live in `IO` monad.

Now, if it's not obvious why order matters in this particular case, remember
than parent resource as well as child resource must be allocated and then
they are freed. When they are freed you won't get the same results (but
rather segmentation fault), so referential transparency is broken. So these
resource-dependent functions should stay in `IO`.

Also, I don't think it's impossible to allocate different objects at the same
address during single program execution. This again would break referential
transparency.